# Subscript Out of Range when pasting from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to press a button on my original workbook to open multiple data files and combine them into one workbook with each file saved as a separate worksheet.
I then want to copy certain ranges from each sheet and paste them into a sheet on the original workbook, shift down on the original sheet and paste the ranges from the next data sheet.

It saves the combined data workbook and opens it but won't run the For Each loop to copy and paste the data into the original workbook.

It triggers an error and won't let me debug to find the source of the issue.

> Subscript Out of Range

Here is a modified version of my code (can't include original file names for client confidentiality).
Assume that "DataFiles" is the combined data workbook and "DataProcessing.xlsm" is the workbook where I'm pasting the values.
The filepath is also originally a shared S:Drive path for all my coworkers to access.

```vb
Sub CombineAndCopyData()
    
    ' Select and combine data files into single workbook
    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*), *.*", , "Select Files", , True)
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Select Files"
    End If
    I = 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    xTempWb.Close False
    Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
        I = I + 1
        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
        xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move , xWb.Sheets(xWb.Sheets.Count)
    Loop
    
    ' Set up combined results file
    TargetFileName = "DataFiles"
    TargetFilePath = "C:\Users\CorToTheWin\Documents\Do Not Delete\" + TargetFileName + ".xlsx"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=TargetFilePath
    Workboo  ks("DataFiles").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
    ' Loop through each sheet and copy to file
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Setting the starting target rows in DataProcessing.xlsm
    TargetRow = 5
    TargetRowName = 4
    For Each ws In Workbooks("DataFiles").Worksheets
       
        ' Selection 1
        ws.Range("B16").Copy
        TargetCellName = "A" & TargetRowName
        Windows("DataProcessing.xlsm").Activate
        Range(TargetCellName).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        ' Selection 2
        ws.Range("C17:C26").Copy
        TargetCell = "B" & TargetRow
        Windows("DataProcessing.xlsm").Activate
        Range(TargetCell).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        ' Selection 3
        ws.Range("E17:E26").Copy
        TargetCell = "C" & TargetRow
        Windows("DataProcessing.xlsm").Activate
        Range(TargetCell).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        ' Selection 4
        ws.Range("D17:D26").Copy
        TargetCell = "D" & TargetRow
        Windows("DataProcessing.xlsm").Activate
        Range(TargetCell).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        ' Move the target rows down a few rows
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 12
        TargetRowName = TargetRowName + 12
        TargetRowSTD = TargetRowSTD + 12

    Next ws
    
    Workbooks(TargetFileName).Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

I tried altering the ways to activate the data workbook, tried a different looping code block, and tried saving the data workbook to a local file instead. All resulted in the same Subscript error.

Comment: `Workboo  ks("DataFiles").Activate` a typo in the question (not in the actual code), I presume? Also, please use [Option Explicit](https://excelchamps.com/vba/option-explicit/) There are so so many undeclared variables..

Comment: Don't you want to use `xWb` instead of `Workbooks("DataFiles")`?

Comment: If you hit "Debug", then it should tell you — so that you can tell *us* which **line** the error is in.  Also, consider reading [How to avoid using `Select` in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: After declaring all the variables, I was able to let it run without issues. DataProcessing and the files I selected were on a network drive as well.

Comment: Is it the `Workbooks("DataFiles").Activate` line ? If in File Explorer you have the view option "File name extensions" ticked then use `Workbooks("DataFiles.xlsx").Activate` or just remove that line as it is the ActiveWorkbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook` by defining references to the workbooks.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CombineAndCopyData()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\CorToTheWin\Documents\Do Not Delete\"
    Const FILENAME = "Datafiles.xlsx"

    Dim xFilesToOpen, i As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbData As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*), *.*", , "Select Files", , True)
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Select Files"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'open first workbook and copy of sheet 1 to new wb
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(1), ReadOnly:=True)
    wb.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wbData = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' copy rest of files and save
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks("Dataprocessing.xlsm")
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.ActiveSheet
    
    Dim TargetRow: TargetRow = 4
    With wbData
        For i = 2 To UBound(xFilesToOpen)
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(i))
            wb.Sheets(1).Move , .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        Next
        .SaveAs FOLDER & FILENAME
        MsgBox i - 1 & " sheets copied to " & FOLDER & FILENAME, vbInformation
        
        For Each ws In .Sheets
            ' Selection 1
            wsTarget.Cells(TargetRow, "A") = ws.Range("B16").Value2
            TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
        
            ' Selection 2
            wsTarget.Cells(TargetRow, "B").Resize(10) = ws.Range("C17:C26").Value2
    
            ' Selection 3
            wsTarget.Cells(TargetRow, "C").Resize(10) = ws.Range("E17:E26").Value2
        
            ' Selection 4
            wsTarget.Cells(TargetRow, "D").Resize(10) = ws.Range("D17:D26").Value2
            
            ' Move the target rows down a few rows
            TargetRow = TargetRow + 11
        Next
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox wbTarget.Name & " Updated", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```